# How to add/update text of elements created with insertAdjacentHTML method?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create `p` tags and inside them `span` with `insertAdjacentHTML` method and give each one of them unique id, and after that I want to change or update the `textContent`, but I don't know the reason why it is not working?. If you have the solution please help me.

```js
const wraper = document.querySelector("#wraper")
const place2 = "afterbegin";
const textOfTimerTile = `
<div class="dataWraper">
<p id="program"><span id="programData"></span></p>
<p id="machineId"><span id="machineIdData"></span></p>
</div>
`;
wraper.insertAdjacentHTML(place2, textOfTimerTile);

const program = document.getElementById("program");
const programData = document.getElementById("programData");
const machineId = document.getElementById("machineId");
const machineIdData = document.getElementById("machineIdData");

program.textContent = "Program";
programData.textContent = "Program Span";
machineId.textContent= "Machine ID";
machineIdData.textContent= "Machine Span";
console.log("p tag ", program);
console.log("span ", programData)
```

```css
#program, #machineId{
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
background-color: green
}
#programData, #machineIdData{
width:100px;
height: 60px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wraper"></div>
```

Comment: "_give each one of them unique id_" Sounds like you're creating more than one of these elements, `id` is not a correct tool to make a bulk of elements recognizable.

Comment: The main issue is that `program.textContent = "Program";` replaces everything inside `program`, so `<span id="programData"></span>` will disappear from the UI but still be present as a reference in the variable `programData`.

Comment: @chrwahl exactly as you said happens, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I don't know that complete context for your code, but an alternative could be to make use of the [template literal (template string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that you already defined.

```js
const wraper = document.querySelector("#wraper");

let programtext = "Program";
let programDatatext = "Program Span";
let machineIdtext = "Machine ID";
let machineIdDatatext = "Machine Span";

const textOfTimerTile = `<div class="dataWraper">
<p id="program">${programtext}<span id="programData">${programDatatext}</span></p>
<p id="machineId">${machineIdtext}<span id="machineIdData">${machineIdDatatext}</span></p>
</div>`;

wraper.innerHTML = textOfTimerTile;
```

```css
#program,
#machineId {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green
}

#programData,
#machineIdData {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wraper"></div>
```

Comment: your solution is the best it works for me as well. It doese not overwrite the `span` inside `p` tag. I give my tick to your solution thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `program.textContent = "Program";` you're actually removing the span from the page (you can see that in the browser's dev tools).

What you can do instead is `program.insertAdjacentText('afterbegin', 'Program')`

Comment: it doesn't work also when I try to use this method, it do the same and remove the span tag!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext):

> Both textContent and innerText remove child nodes when altered. It is impossible to insert the nodes again into any other element or into the same element after doing so.

Meaning you override and inner elements of your `<p>`'s.
If you want, I suggest use `innerHTML` and **add** to it text instead of destroying your html structure with `textContent`.

However, since you set a new `innerHTML` you need to get the inner elements again.

To sum up -

```js
const wraper = document.querySelector("#wraper")
const place2 = "afterbegin";
const textOfTimerTile = `
<div class="dataWraper">
<p id="program"><span id="programData"></span></p>
<p id="machineId"><span id="machineIdData"></span></p>
</div>
`;
wraper.insertAdjacentHTML(place2, textOfTimerTile);

const program = document.getElementById("program");
const machineId = document.getElementById("machineId");


program.innerHTML = "Program" + program.innerHTML;
const programData = document.getElementById("programData");
programData.innerHTML = "Program Span";

machineId.innerHTML = "Machine ID" + machineId.innerHTML;
const machineIdData = document.getElementById("machineIdData");
machineIdData.innerHTML = "Machine Span";
```

```css
#program,
#machineId {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green
}

#programData,
#machineIdData {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wraper"></div>
```

Comment: Attaiya good solution thanks, here it works but doesn't work for me I don't know why anyway thank you for your solution.